# Need a service that provides "Most tweeted articles in the last 24 hours"

Tags: looking-for-a-script, twitter

any recommendations for a service that would fill the following 4 requirements:

- Gather a list of the most tweeted articles
- within a 24hour time range
- for a given site domain
- Easily loaded client-site (javascript or an iframe)

Mockup:

[image: mockup]

Comment: Most tweeted...from where? Your own site? And if so, given that "for a given Twitter account" doesn't seem to make sense, since it would be *other* accounts sending out tweets to these articles. Can you explain that more clearly? Also, are you specifically looking for a *service* or possibly also a self-installed tool? (Someone else added the looking-for-a-script tag, which may not apply.)

Comment: Sorry, i reworded that - thanks for pointing out. I added a mockup of what i'm trying to achieve. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a basic script using the [twitter api](https://dev.twitter.com/) to [return the information](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search).

> Notice: As of April 1st 2010, the Search API provides an option to
>   retrieve "popular tweets" in addition to real-time search results. In
>   an upcoming release, this will become the default and clients that
>   don't want to receive popular tweets in their search results will have
>   to explicitly opt-out. See the result_type parameter below for more
>   information.